# Perl CSV_XS module installation failed using Cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

I am having problems installed a CPAN module Text::CSV_XS using Cygwin.

I did a

```
$ cpan Text::CSV_XS
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
.... Every was good till:.....

Writing Makefile for Text::CSV_XS
cp CSV_XS.pm blib/lib/Text/CSV_XS.pm
/usr/bin/perl.exe /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5 .10/ExtUtils/typemap  CSV_XS.xs > CSV_XS.xsc && mv CSV_XS.xsc CSV_XS.c
gcc-4 -c    -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -p ipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3    -DVERSION=\"0.8 8\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"0.88\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   CSV_XS.c
/bin/sh: gcc-4: command not found
Makefile:330: recipe for target `CSV_XS.o' failed
make: *** [CSV_XS.o] Error 127
  HMBRAND/Text-CSV_XS-0.88.tgz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I installed another module earlier, without problem.

```
Make is installed
gcc is installed
```

/bin/sh returns a new shell.

```
$ /bin/sh

$
```

Answer (score 7):

Important note: as of this writing, gcc4 is now in the obsolete packages section which is hidden by default in the Cygwin installer.

Answer (score 6):

Fire up the Cygwin packagre manager (`setup.exe`) and install `gcc4`. Use the search facility to locate the package in the manager. While you're at it, also install `make`, `autoconf` and `automake`. You'll find all these packages in the `devel` section.

Then retry, it will succeed, I just tested it:

```
MiLu@Dago: ~ > cpan Text::CSV_XS
...
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.bs
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.dll
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin/Text/CSV_XS.pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/Text.CSV_XS.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/perllocal.pod
  HMBRAND/Text-CSV_XS-0.88.tgz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

Comment: Yes! That was it.  Needed gcc4. The other packages were installed already.  Thank you.

Comment: @B1 - If that solved it, consider [*accepting* the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the hook next to the up and down arrows, which will increase my score. This is then called *reputation* (or just *rep*), and it is the way this site works. You might have seen it before on other sites.

Comment: These steps (installing make,autoconf,automake) helped me installed DBI under Cygwin. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem with installing Lab::VISA on cygwin. Can anybody help me with that? It eerors at this line in the Makefile .c$(OBJ_EXT):
 $(CCCMD) $(CCCDLFLAGS) "-I$(PERL_INC)" $(PASTHRU_DEFINE) $(DEFINE) $*.c, saying visa_wrap.c:1558:18: fatal error: visa.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.